# How to show that following relation is true for matrix multiplication?

Tags: matrices, vectors, vector-analysis, matrix-equations

I have one complex matrix $\mathbb{A}$ (of size $L\times L$) and one complex column vector $\mathbb{b}$ (of size $L$). How can I show that $$\mathbb{A^Hbb^HA}=\sum_{i=1}^{L}\mathbb{c_i^Hb}\mathbb{c_i}^T\mathbb{b^*}$$ where $\mathbb{c_i^H}$ is the $i$-th row of $\mathbb{A^H}$. Any help in this regard will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance. Please note that superscript $\mathbb{H}$ denotes the hermitian operator and superscript $T$ denotes the transpose operator. Further the superscript $*$ denotes the conjugate.

Comment: What is definition of  $A^H$? Is it $A$ power $H$ where $H$ is some positive integer??

Comment: @David $\mathbb{H}$ denotes the hermitian operator. I have also added these definitions in my question.

Comment: apparently this looks like matrix multiplication. By the way, isnt that $y$ is $b$? if not, what is $y$?

Comment: @David yes it should be $\mathbb{b}$ and I have corrected it. I tried to do the multiplication but I failed to show the equality of both sides therefore I posted this question.

Comment: First Calculate $A^H b = (c_1^H b, \dots, c_L^H b)^T$. This observation should lead you to the answer.

Comment: @David I do not know how because when I multiply $\mathbb{A^Hb}$ with $\mathbb{b^H}$ I get $$\left[ {\begin{array}{cccc}
   \mathbb{c_1^Hb}b_1^* & \mathbb{c_1^Hb}b_1^* & \cdots & \mathbb{c_1^Hb}b_L^*\\
\vdots \\   \mathbb{c_L^Hb}b_1^* & \mathbb{c_1^Hb}b_2^* & \cdots & \mathbb{c_1^Hb}b_L^*\\
  \end{array} } \right]$$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78868/discussion-between-david-and-frank-moses).

Comment: @David and when I multiply the above quantity to $\mathbb{A}$ I do not get the form that is present on the right of the equation in my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us first calculate $A^H b$ where $H$ is the hermitian operator. That is,
$$ (A^H)_{ij} = A_{ji}^*$$
where $*$ represents the complex conjugate.

\begin{align}
A^H b b^H A & = (A^H b) (b^H A) \\
            & = (A^H b) (A ^H b )^H \\
            & = y y^H \text{ where } y = A^H b
\end{align}

Now calculate $y $.

$$ y = A^H b  = \begin{bmatrix} c_1^H b \\ \vdots \\ c_L^H b \end{bmatrix}$$
where $c_i^H$ is the $i$th row of $A^H$.

Now note that 
$$y ^H = \begin{bmatrix} c_1^H b \\ \vdots \\ c_L^H b \end{bmatrix} ^ H = \begin{bmatrix} (c_1^H b)^* & \dots & (c_L^H b)^* \end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix} c_1^T b^* & \dots & c_L^T b^* \end{bmatrix}(\text{ do you know why?})$$
Thats it,

Now its just a matrix multiplication.
$$ y y^H = \sum_{i = 1} ^L c_i ^ H b c_i^T b^*$$

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Yes I know why. I think you should have written $\mathbb{y^Hy}$ instead of $\mathbb{yy}^T$. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes...Thanks. corrected